# Fill a div with other div in height and width

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, flexbox

I have a div that can have dimensions in percent or fixed; I need to completely fill the div, with other divs of equal size, to form a grid.

Some idea?

Edit:
I want to generate a grid similar to the one immediately visible below

[image: grid]

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use flex display. I've wrote simple example to show usage with fixed container: http://jsbin.com/huqituhewu/edit?html,css,output. You can make child div's fill the space in the following way (it's part from the jsbin link):

```
.container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.container > * {
  flex: 1;
}
```

There is a nice tutorial about flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Play a little more to form a nice grid, if you want multi row display.

EDIT: I've added flex-wrap and min-width styles. Now rows are formed when there are more items in your container. Notice, when there are less than 4 items in the row, they stretch nicely to the full width. If there are 4 or more items (100%/25% (min-width = 25%) = 4) they keep the width and wrap. Play with amount of child divs and min/max-width to see the effects.

Comment: I thank you for the good suggestion, I'm looking at the link you suggested ... the question I ask now is the following:

How can I generate as many divs as the free space of the container?

Comment: Wouldn't be a simple table the best solution to this?
http://jsbin.com/dulowupota/1/edit?html,css,js,output